# Interpolating and Decimating CIC filter based on sinc function

Tags: filters, frequency-spectrum, filter-design, dsp-core

How to realize a sinc function using CIC filter for decimation and interpolation ??? Can I combine interpolation and decimaton methods inorder to get the complete response of a sinc function???

Comment: do you want the $\text{sinc}$ to be in frequency or time domain?

Comment: The real question, and you should probably edit your question to include that, or ask a new one, is *why* you want that?

Answer (score 1):

The frequency/z domain response of a $N$-Stage CIC filter is, invariably [1]:

$$\begin{align}
H(z) &= \frac{(1-z^{-RM})^N}{(1-z^{-1})^N}\\
&= \left(\sum\limits_{k=0}^{RM-1}{z^{-k}}\right)^N
\end{align}$$

with $R$ being the rate change, and $M$ being the delay length. You can assume $M=1$ (you don't get a special shape if you assume larger $M$, just sharper response).

For $N=1$, you get the "boring" observation that you've built a moving average filter (which, in fact, has sinc-shape in frequency domain). But that's really just due to the fact that that you really did just that – build a recursive MA.

The magnitude response is usually (as in [1]) represented as

$$
\lvert H(f)\rvert = \left\lvert \frac{\sin(\pi M f)}{\pi M f} \right\rvert^N
$$

which goes to say you *only* get the sinc shape for $N=1$. In other words, a moving average. Which really shouldn't surprise you – the moving average is the time-domain rectangle, and the Fourier transform of that is the sinc.

---

[1] *CIC Filter Introduction*, Matthew P. Donadio, July 2000. [Available Online](http://dspguru.com/sites/dspguru/files/cic.pdf)

Comment: To clarify, the CIC with N=1 only approximates a Sinc, and only reasonably well for large M. For small M it is what I would call an "aliased Sinc".  I mention this minor point not to detract from this good answer but in case anyone wants a precise Sinc function response at least over the limited frequency range applied. That said I believe the final magnitude response is incorrect for general M where M is any positive integer. @MarcusMüller would you agree?